# E4 RCP NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: eclipse-rcp, noclassdeffounderror, e4

I am trying to use classes from other projects in my E4 RCP application but I receive this error. I have a LoginHandler class that uses a LoginController class from another project to validate credentials however it seems it cant find the class and I don't know why.

Here is the log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-12-10 14:25:08.571
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'com.kleinknecht.ui.parts.CloseHandler' from bundle '87'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.kleinknecht.ui.parts.CloseHandler cannot be found by ATS_userManagement_RCP_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon.processActiveHandler(HandlerProcessingAddon.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon.postConstruct(HandlerProcessingAddon.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:990)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-12-10 14:25:13.308
!MESSAGE Internal Error
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/klk/userManagement/controller/LoginController
    at com.kleinknecht.ui.parts.LoginHandler.execute(LoginHandler.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:196)
    at com.kleinknecht.ui.parts.LoginDialog$1.widgetSelected(LoginDialog.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.klk.userManagement.controller.LoginController cannot be found by ATS_userManagement_RCP_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 39 more
```

Here is the LoginHandler code and the classpath of my RCP project:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/ATS_core"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/ATS_errorList"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/ATS_gui"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/ATS_model"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/ATS_update"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/ATS_userAuthentication"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/ATS_userManagement"/>
</classpath>
```

The controllers are located in the ATS_userAuthentication path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath is not used by Eclipse plug-ins. Only the MANIFEST.MF is consulted to find out what other plug-ins and classes to use. Plug-ins can only use classes in other plug-ins.

The MANIFEST.MF of the plug-in that wants to use something in another plug-in must use the `Require-Bundle` entry to reference the plug-in or use the `Import-Package` entry to let Eclipse find the package in any installed plug-in.

The MANIFEST.MF of the plug-in that provides a class must export the package that contains the class using `Export-Package`

So, for example, I have a `greg.music.core` plug-in which exports various packages:

```
Export-Package: greg.music.core.common,
 greg.music.core.databinding,
 greg.music.core.e4util,
 greg.music.core.editor,
 greg.music.core.expression,
 greg.music.core.preferences,
 greg.music.core.progress,
 greg.music.core.services,
 greg.music.core.showin,
 greg.music.core.util,
 greg.music.core.views,
 greg.music.core.xml
```

And another plug-in which imports from that plug-in:

```
Require-Bundle: greg.music.core
```

Note: For testing inside Eclipse you do also have to have the classpath set up. The MANIFEST.MF editor will do this for you.